# renaming files in python giving 'Error 2'

Tags: python

i am trying to bulk rename some pdfs in a directory

```
if len(self.toLoc.get()) == 0:
    searchRev = "_R" + newRev 
    for filename in os.listdir(App.pdfDir):
        sep = searchesri
        rest = filename.split(sep, 1)[0] + searchRev
        os.rename(filename, rest)
else:
    searchRev = "_R" + newRev + fromLocation + toLocation
    print searchRev
```

When I run it, it gives me the error

```
  File "F:\TOOLS\PythonTools\VCR.py", line 411, in renameMaps
    os.rename(filename, rest)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I can print filename in the for loop and get results though....

Comment: I think you need to provide the full path to files as well.

Comment: `os.path.join` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.rename` requires the *full* paths to the files, but `os.listdir` only returns their names.

You can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to make the full paths that `os.rename` requires:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(App.pdfDir, filename), rest)
```

Comment: makes way more sense now. Thanks for the help man, appreciate it.

Comment: hate to be a bother, but any idea why its giving me an error WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists? When I print I get 
('F:/Jobs2014\\07510\\PDF\\OFFICE\\14075010RM_R0.pdf', '14075010RM_R0_5-5-5-5')
so they files are different... ?

Comment: On `Windows os.rename` raises an error when you try to rename a file to something that already exists. You can avoid this error by using `import shutil; shutil.move(src, dest)` instead of `os.rename(src, dest)`.

Comment: @user1079506 - You are not a bother at all; that's why I'm here. :)    However, it would be best for you to ask a new question so that you can receive proper help regarding this new problem, instead of me troubleshooting this with you in the comments.